# How do I resolve an Invalid Capsule Name?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

When attempting to create a new capsule, Bixby Studio says my capsule name is invalid. How do I make sure I'm using a valid capsule name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must ensure that your capsule name adheres to the following requirements:

- The longest your capsule name (not including playground or other namespace) can be is 30 characters.
- First character must be a lowercase a-z
- All other characters must be either a-z, A-Z, 0-9, or _

You can find this information as well as a few example names in [this article](https://support.bixbydevelopers.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019306334) found on the [Bixby Developer Help Center's FAQ page](https://support.bixbydevelopers.com/hc/en-us/sections/360000587993-FAQ).

Answer (score 0):

The most frequent problem is the name should be written with a lowercase letter. This is different than in InteliJ or Android Studio where the project name can be entered from a capital letter and the package will be created automatically from a small one.